# Uniform continuity exchanges derivative

Tags: uniform-convergence

I am trying to prove the following thing:

Let I = [a,b]. Let f and g be two functions from I to $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $f_n$ a succession of functions  that is $C^1(I)$.

I know that $f_n$ converges punctually to f.

I also know that $f'_n$ converges uniformly to g.

I want to prove the following things:
$f$ is $C^1$, $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ and  $f' = g$.

Here it is my attempt:
I define $\widetilde{f} = f(x_0) + \int_{x}^{x_0}g(t)dt$.

Now, if I can prove that $\widetilde{f} = f$ and that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $\widetilde{f}$, then $f' = g$ follows from Fundamental theorem of calculus.

Now I write my definitions:

Punctual convergence:

$\forall x \in [a,b]$, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there exists $N(x,\epsilon)$ such that $\forall n>N(x,\epsilon$) we have $\vert f_n(x) - f(x)\vert < \epsilon$

Uniform convergence:

$\forall x \in [a,b]$, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there exists $N(\epsilon)$ such that $\forall n>N(\epsilon$) we have $\vert f'_n(x) - g(x)\vert < \epsilon$

Now however I struggle to keep going. Should I consider the epsilons and the N's in the two definitions different, right?

Then how do I complete the proof?

Comment: A note, convergenza puntuale is pointwise convergence in english, not punctual convergence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I would do it:

Using that the $f_n$ are $C^1(I)$, write 
$$
f_n(x)=f_n(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^xf_n'(t)\mathrm dt
$$
for $x,x_0\in I$. Now taking limits and using that $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise we have 
$$
f(x)=f(x_0)+\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{x_0}^xf_n'(t)\mathrm dt
$$
Finally, using uniformity of the limit of $f_n'\to g$, interchange limit and integral and find 
$$
f(x)=f(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^xg(t)\mathrm dt
$$
From here we see that $f$ is $C^1$ with derivative $g$.

For uniformity of $f_n\to f$, use our formula for $f_n$ to estimate
$$
|f(x)-f_n(x)|=\left|f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)+ \int_{x_0}^x g(t)-f_n'(t)\mathrm dt  \right|\\
\stackrel{\text{triangle ineq.}}{\leq} \left| \int_{x_0}^x |g(t)-f_n'(t)|\mathrm dt  \right|+|f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)|\\
\leq \left| \sup_{t\in [a,b]}|g(t)-f_n'(t)|\int_{x_0}^x \mathrm dt\right|+|f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)|\\
=|x-x_0|\sup_{t\in [a,b]}|g(t)-f_n'(t)|+|f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)|\\
\leq |a-b|\sup_{t\in [a,b]}|g(t)-f_n'(t)|+|f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)|\to 0
$$
as $n\to \infty$ independently of $x$ by assumption that $f_n'\to g$ uniformly. Uniform convergence of the $f_n$ then follows.

In answer to  your question, for any given epsilon, you can find an $N(\epsilon)$ making your estimate on the derivative hold, and then you can find $N_1(x,\epsilon)$ to make the estimate on the difference $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ hold. These will in general be different natural numbers.

It is worth learning the following criterion for uniform convergence: $f_n\to f$ uniformly on some domain $D$ if and only if 
$$
\sup_{x\in D}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq M_n
$$
where $M_n$ is a sequence tending to $0$. This avoids messing about with $\epsilon$'s and makes things cleaner.

Comment: I think I understood everything apart from a detail: I think I should prove that the sup of the difference in absolute value is less than epsilon, is this equivalent?     The way I see it is that you did the sup in both the left and right part of the inequality, is that right?

Comment: Sure, this is the same thing. To make things cleaner you can fix an $\epsilon>0$ and choose $N(\epsilon)$ with $\sup|g(t)-f_n'(t)|<\epsilon/|a-b|$. As the final estimate is independent of $x$, yes, you may take the supremum on the left and right hand side of the inequality (in $x$).

Comment: Ok, I see your point. I have one final question: I think you made disappear the term $\vert f(x_0) - f_n(x_0)\vert$ when calculating $\vert f(x) - f_n(x)\vert$. Is that because when n goes to infinity $f_n$ converges pointwise to f(x)? I would personally dominate that term with $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ on that term and a $\frac{\epsilon}{2\vert a - b\vert}$ on the other to make things smoother. Is that right as well?

Comment: How sloppy of me, I forgot it and will edit it in. You can certainly do that or note again that the estimate you get in the end holds for all $x$, you may still take the supremum over $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of $\tilde f$ should be$$\tilde f(x)=f(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^xg(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$With this definition\begin{align}\left\lvert\tilde f(x)-f_n(x)\right\rvert&=\left\lvert f(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^xg(t)\,\mathrm dt-\left(f_n(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^xf_n'(t)\,\mathrm dt\right)\right\rvert\\&=\left\lvert f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^xg(t)-f_n'(t)\,\mathrm dt\right\rvert\\&\leqslant\left\lvert f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)\right\rvert+\left\lvert\int_{x_0}^xg(t)-f_n'(t)\,\mathrm dt\right\rvert\\&\leqslant\left\lvert f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)\right\rvert+\int_{x_0}^x\left\lvert g(t)-f_n'(t)\right\rvert\,\mathrm dt.\end{align}Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x_0)=f(x_0)$ and since $(f_n')_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges uniformly to $g$, it follows from this that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges uniformly to $\tilde f$.

Comment: I think there is a typo with $z_0$ and $x_0$. Apart from that, I have a question: I think I should prove that the sup of the difference in absolute value is less than epsilon, as definition of uniform convergence, right? Is it equivalent to prove it in this way?

Comment: @LudovicoBessi Yes, it was a typo, and I've edited my answer. And yes, you should prove that $\sup\bigl\lvert\tilde f(x)-f_n(x)\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon$ if $n$ is large enough. For that, take $n$ large enough to have $\sup\bigl\lvert f(x_o)-f_n(x_0)\bigr\rvert<\frac\varepsilon2$ and that $\sup\bigl\lvert g(t)-f_n'(t)\bigr\rvert<\frac\varepsilon{2(b-a)}$ and it will follow from my computations that that will do.